# Some complex Threading concept

Tags: java

how to Execute threads sequentially ? (e.g i have 3 threads T1,T2,T3 and i want to start these threads same time but ensure that they should run sequentially one after other like first T1 then T2 and at last T3.)

```
    Thread t1= new Thread(new Runnable()
      {
        void run()
          {System.out.println("inside Thread1");}
      });


    Thread t2= new Thread(new Runnable()
      {
        void run()
          {System.out.println("inside Thread2");}
      });

    Thread t3= new Thread(new Runnable()
      {
        void run()
          {System.out.println("inside Thread3");}
      });

     t1.start();
     t2.strat();
     t3.start();
```

output:
      inside Thread1
      inside Thread2
      inside Thread3
each time u run o/p should be as shown above.

Comment: How about running your stuff in one thread?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? At the moment for me the question is what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: By "threads" you probably mean "tasks". If not, then this is an artificial question about behavior you would never want to appear in a functional application.

Comment: If you mean tasks see SingleThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: If you are running, multiple task sequentially, why do you need multiple threads? You can do it with single thread.

Answer (score 6):

In my humble opinion, you perhaps do not need threads, just call T1(), T2(), T3() methods sequentially in your code?
Threads are used to run multiple tasks in parallel.

Comment: but dude if interviewer asks then what to do i faced the same in ALcatel-lucent in recent past.

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize these threads through  **flag/s**. You can also use inbuilt synchronizers provided by Java like **BlockingQueue**.

Comment: Again that would be for tasks and not threads I suppose. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: You can tie up multiple threads for the same task. Question is just about executing mutiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Use BlockingQueues to synchronize the threads

```
    final BlockingQueue q1 = new SynchronousQueue();
    final BlockingQueue q2 = new SynchronousQueue();
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            ... 
            try {
                q1.put(new Object());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        };
    };
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                q1.take();
                ...
                q2.put(new Object());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t3 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                q2.take();
                ...
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Threads are used to run multiple tasks at a same time.

In your case you need different methods called sequentially rather than Threads.

You should use:

```
class Methods_Than_Threads{
void T1()
{
    //something
}
void T2()
{
    //something
}
void T3()
{
    //something
}
public static void main(String []args)
{
    T1();//First T1
    T2();//Second T2
    T3();//Third T3
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the actual tasks from how they are executed. I.e. don't extend `Thread` and overwrite `run`, instead implement `Runnable` as the task and don't care about the way it is executed.

That way you can design (+change later) the way you execute tasks independently from the actual implementation of a task.

E.g. Call each `.run()` directly if you want to execute them after each other or let some `Executor` handle them or even run them via `new Thread` manually.

If they have to wait on each other you could also use a `Future`. For example:

```
class ProcessingChainElement implements Callable<String> {
    private final Future<String> previous;
    public ProcessingChainElement(Future<String> previousResult) {
        previous = previousResult;
    }
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // prepare something that may take some time but does not depend on
        // any previous result
        Thread.sleep(500);

        // get result from previous task, this blocks until it is available
        result = previous.get() + " [" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "]";

        return result;
    }
}
```

And build a chain of tasks that can be executed in any way you want.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Future<String> result1 = executor.submit(...
Future<String> result2 = executor.submit(new ProcessingChainElement(result1));
...
```

Result is that each task can wait on results of a previous task but may very well run in parallel if there is anything that can be run in parallel.

Example http://ideone.com/VAg8q3 demonstrates that 3 tasks that take >= 500ms each and depend on each other could be done much quicker than actually running them in sequence.